# Exception Handling SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, user-defined-functions

I created a user defined function that calculates the quantity in stock for a product

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_quantityInStock(
    oldProductQuantity IN INTEGER,
    orderedQuan IN INTEGER)
    RETURN INTEGER
IS
    v_newQuantity INTEGER;
    v_oldQuantity INTEGER;
    v_orderedQuan INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_newquantity := oldProductQuantity - orderedQuan;
    RETURN v_newquantity;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Please check your data.');
END function_quantityInstock;
```

I then create a trigger that updates the table by calling the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_QUANTITY AFTER INSERT ON ordered_product
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_oldQuantity INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT PRODUCT_QUANTITYINSTOCK INTO v_oldQuantity
    FROM   product
    WHERE  product_id = :NEW.product_id;

    UPDATE PRODUCT
    SET    product_quantityinstock =
             function_quantityINSTOCK(v_oldQuantity, :NEW.ORDERED_PRODUCTQUANTITY)
    WHERE product_id = :NEW.product_id;
END;
```

I want to display a message when the user enters invalid data but my exception block doesnt do that.

I use the following anonyomus block to test the function:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    v_productID    ordered_product.product_id%TYPE:= &ProductID;
    v_orderID      ordered_product.order_id%TYPE:=&OrderID;
    v_orderedQuan  ordered_product.ordered_productQuantity%TYPE := &OrderedProductQuantity;
    v_totalCost    ordered_product.ordered_productTotalCost%TYPE := '&TotalCost';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ordered_product VALUES
    (v_orderID, v_productID, v_orderedQuan, v_totalCost);

    dbms_output.put_line('A new record has been inserted.');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Invalid data!');
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error! Please check your values.'|| SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: This isn't SQL Server syntax. what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is pure PL/SQL - Oracle. I am not sure why you're question ended up in the SQL Server area.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `exec dbms_output.enable(10000)` and therefore not be seeing the output.

You should throw the exception using

```
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Please check your data.');
```

Also it's bad practice to catch all exceptions using `when others` and then ignore them.

Comment: He has a `set serveroutput on` at the top so dbms_output should be OK. Agree about exception handling though.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't rely on dbms_output.put_line to pass information around. Instead, rely on the standard exception handling, e.g. RAISE or RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. Also, given that you're trying to find the new quantity, I'd move the select on the product table into the function, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_quantityinstock(p_product_id IN product.product_product_id p_orderedquan IN INTEGER)
  RETURN INTEGER IS
  v_newquantity INTEGER;

  e_not_enough_stock EXCEPTION;
  e_not_enough_stock_num INTEGER := -20001;

  e_no_product_exists_num INTEGER := -20002;

  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_not_enough_stock, -20001);
BEGIN
  SELECT product_quantityinstock - orderedquan
  INTO   v_newquantity
  FROM   product
  WHERE  product_id = :new.product_id;

  IF v_newquantity < 0
  THEN
    RAISE e_not_enough_stock;
  END IF;

  RETURN v_newquantity;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    raise_application_error(-e_no_product_exists_num,
                    'No product exists for product_id = ' || product_id);

  -- no need to check for TOO_MANY_ROWS if product_id is the primary/unique key on the product table.
  WHEN e_not_enough_stock THEN
    raise_application_error(e_not_enough_stock_num,
                    'Not enough stock present to fulfil the order for product_id = ' ||
                    product_id);

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(SQLCODE,
                    'Unexpected error occurred whilst finding new quantity for product_id = ' ||
                    product_id || ': ' || SQLERRM);

END function_quantityinstock;
/
```

You'd need to change the function name though, to reflect the action that it's doing, since it's returning the new quantity in stock...